# $n$th prime number

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Is there an explicit formula that tells us what the $n$th prime number is if we know what the $nth$ squareful number is? If there is, what are its applications, and if there isn't, what use would such a formula be, if any?

If there is no explicit formula, but a statement that describes the asymptotic relationship between primes and squarefuls, I would be grateful to hear.

Comment: If there were a formula for the primes, it would be rather famous indeed.

Comment: There is no formula for the squarefuls either, but my question is, is there a formula that describes one in terms of the other?

Comment: To my knowledge, no such formula exists. Should such a formula exist? Well, you can describe any integer in terms of its prime factors, so if you could give necessary or sufficient conditions on the integer $n$ to be squareful, then you could be able to explain said relation using primes instead. However, such a formulation would undoubtedly be only in some limiting sense. But again, it is not known.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. If an integer $q$ was known to squareful, but its prime factorisation unknown, could it be used to define its prime partner? Do such partnerships exist? Further to that, if $q$ was known to be squareful, and it was known to be the $n$th squareful number, could the $m$th prime number be determined, where $m$ is a funcio0n of $n$? If such a relationship were proven to exist, would it have any use in furthering our understanding of number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [plenty of formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeFormulas.html) for the $n$th prime, most of which are useless curiosities. I don't know of any that uses a formula for squareful numbers. We can't really say what applications such a formula would have before actually seeing it.

Comment: Thanks for the link - this helps clear up a few things!

Comment: @martin Again and as the article points out, these functions or relations may generate primes but they do not generate all of $\mathbb{P}$. Moreover, the function for the $n$th prime still requires one know most (if not all), the primes before it. So it's not a typical function and is more defined recursively. Again, as the article points out and as Bruno Joyal notes, these formulas are often useless as they require even more work than just the standard sieve to find the (next) prime(s).

Comment: @mathematics2x2life Formula (13) gives all primes, and requires no knowledge of previous primes.

Comment: @BrunoJoyal Indeed, you are correct. However, it is very computationally expensive. Nevertheless, I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

There are reasonably good approximations for the n-th prime. And there are reasonably fast methods to count the number of primes ≤ x, running in about O (n^(2/3)).

So if you want to know the n-th prime, a reasonably good method is to use an approximation that gives you x ≈ nth prime. Then you count how many primes ≤ x there are, which should be some number m close to n. Then you use a sieve that is just large enough to guarantee that it covers the n - m primes after x if n > m, or the m - n primes before x if n < m to find the n-th prime.

Comment: The analytic methods are even faster asymptotically, running in $\tilde{O}(x^{1/2})$. I agree that the best method is to approximate the $n$th prime (invert the logarithmic integral), count the primes with a fast method, then adjust as needed.